# cannot access my website after updating apache "404 Not Found"

Tags: php, apache

i have my php website and it was working fine in older version of apache so i decided to update my apache to 2.4, but the problem is when i`m try to access to the index it works fine and when direct to any location it give me "The requested URL was not found on this server" and if i added .php in the url it access fine to the location so what is the problem here please help me this is .htacess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, it often interferes in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Disable `Multiviews`, it can be found in the `Options` directive in httpd.conf or apache2.conf, or if you are using ubuntu, it can be found on some files in `sites-available` folder inside `/etc/apache2/`

Comment: i have already remove `#` from mod_rewrite , i cant find `Multiviews` in `httpd.conf` , i aslo has changed `AllowOverride` to `All` but still not working

Comment: i forget to `restart Apache` so when i restarted it directs fine but still problem that `title` of the page appears and entire `Page` is `White`